# SQL insert on a case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL (Oracle) and I am trying to write a statement that if Parent1 and Parent2 address is different, then I want Parent2 to insert in the next row with the same student information.  The first part (before the CASE statement with the bottom part (FROM, WHERE, GROUP) work by itself but I wanted to being in Parent2 info if it's different from Parent1.

Thanks!

```
SELECT
    MAX(STUDENTS.LAST_NAME) AS LASTNAME, 
    MAX(US.GUARDIAN1_FIRSTNAME || ' ' || US.GUARDIAN1_LASTNAME) AS PARENT1,
    MAX(US.GUARDIAN2_FIRSTNAME || ' ' || US.GUARDIAN2_LASTNAME) AS PARENT2, 
    MAX(US.GUARDIAN1_ADDRESSSTREET) AS PARENTADDRESS

    CASE 
       WHEN (MAX(US.GUARDIAN1_ADDRESSSTREET) <>  MAX(US.GUARDIAN2_ADDRESSSTREET)
INSERT (MAX(STUDENTS.LAST_NAME) AS LASTNAME, 
MAX(' ' || ' ') AS PARENT1,
MAX(US.GUARDIAN2_FIRSTNAME || ' ' || US.GUARDIAN2_LASTNAME) AS PARENT2, 
MAX(US.GUARDIAN2_ADDRESSSTREET)

FROM 
    STUDENTS,
    U_STUDENTSUSERFIELDS US
WHERE 
    US.studentsdcid = students.dcid 
    AND STUDENTS.ENROLL_STATUS = 0
    AND STUDENTS.ENROLLMENT_SCHOOLID = 340
GROUP BY 
    STUDENTS.FAMILY_IDENT
```

I want it to look like this:

```
==============================================================================
| LASTNAME | PARENT1      | PARENT2      | PARENTADDRESS                     |
==============================================================================
| Smith    | Jane Doe     | John Smith   | 1818 Street       |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Smith    |              | John Smith   | 2525 Other Street |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Jones    | Alice Jones  | Mike Jones   | 111 Old Street    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Johnson  | Perl Johnson | Bob Johnson  | 222 Sesame Street |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Apples   | Eddy Apples  | Sally Apples | 555 Street        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Apples   |              | Sally Apples | 333 Helpme Ave.   |
==============================================================================
```

Comment: You seem to be on the wrong path here, you can't conditionally insert here using `CASE`. I would suggest you dumbing down your example to minimal amount of columns and specifying expected results clearer for the purpose of example if you want people to give you a hand.

Comment: First info that you should give: Which dbms is this????

Comment: You could have an `INSERT` with a `SELECT` having the `CASE` for the values to insert but not at all the order you have. You cannot have a `SELECT` with an `INSERT` clause (no such thing allowed)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Why do your guardians name their fists?

Comment: LOL.  Typo.  Fixing now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you:

```
INSERT INTO targettable 
    (
    LASTNAME,
    PARENT1,
    PARENT2,
    PARENTADDRESS
    )
    SELECT 
        LASTNAME,
        PARENT1,
        PARENT2,
        PARENTADDRESS
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT
            s1.LASTNAME AS LASTNAME,
            s1.PARENT1 AS PARENT1,
            s1.PARENT2 AS PARENT2,
            s1.PARENTADDRESS1 AS PARENTADDRESS
        FROM 
            sourcetable AS s1
        UNION 
        SELECT
            s2.LASTNAME AS LASTNAME,
            NULL AS PARENT1,
            s2.PARENT2 AS PARENT2,
            s2.PARENTADDRESS2 AS PARENTADDRESS
        FROM 
            sourcetable AS s2
        WHERE   
            s2.PARENTADDRESS1 = s2.PARENTADDRESS2
        ) AS z
    ORDER BY 
        LASTNAME
        PARENT2
```

Comment: Edited this to remove the 'Alias =  columnlogic' format, and make it 'columnlogic AS alias' because I'm not sure if the first style works in Oracle.